# MySQL randomly dies

Tags: php, mysql, crash

I have an issue with a `mysql` database that randomly just go and die obviously. When this occurs and I try to use `mysql` in the terminal this occurs:

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'
```

What causes this? If I restart the service it works splendid until the next random occurance when it stops working again. Am all open for ideas.

Comment: Have you check the logs?

Comment: show us the logs and we'll tell you who you are!

Answer (score 0):

You are not mentioned your OS, mysql version, XAMPP/WAMPP here. There are some reason for this error. 
If OS is windows.

1. If you have installed XAMPP more than one in various driver of your system, this error may happen
2. If you installed skype, It may be using mysql default port 3306.

Clear your browser cache and try it.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was memory related. The system killed processes for more essential parts.